# Spring: Bean property is not writable or has an invalid setter method

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I know this question has been asked multiple times but to my eyes everything is correct.  I've also deleted my code from Eclipse and let the IDE create the getters/setters but no avail.

Here's my error in weblogic:

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'gpsDataAllStopsSql' of bean class [com.fedex.dire.webservices.direservice.dao.GPSDataDaoImpl]: Bean property 'gpsDataAllStopsSql' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?

Here's my Bean & Property in my context:

```
<bean id="dataDao" class="com.text.service.dao.DataDaoImpl" >
      <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
      <property name="gpsDataAllStopsSql">
          <value><![CDATA[SELECT A.XML_DATA,B.ADDR1,B.ADDR2,B.POSTALCODE  FROM GPS.EVENT_STAMP A LEFT OUTER JOIN DB.SCAN B ON  A.FAC_IORG_NBR=B.FACILITY AND A.SCANNER_DATE=B.SCANDATE AND A.SCANNER_ID=B.SCANNERID AND A.PD_START_TIME=B.PDSTART WHERE FAC_IORG_NBR = ?  AND SCANNER_DATE = CAST(? AS DATE) AND SCANNER_ID = ? AND PD_START_TIME = ?]]></value>
    </property> 
      <property name="gpsDataSql">
          <value><![CDATA[SELECT A.XML_DATA,A.STOP_NUMBER,B.ADDR1,B.ADDR2,B.POSTALCODE FROM GPS.EVENT_STAMP A LEFT OUTER JOIN DB.SCAN B ON  A.STOP_NUMBER=B.STOP# AND A.FAC_IORG_NBR=B.FACILITY AND A.SCANNER_DATE=B.SCANDATE AND A.SCANNER_ID=B.SCANNERID AND A.PD_START_TIME=B.PDSTART WHERE FAC_IORG_NBR = ?  AND SCANNER_DATE = CAST(? AS DATE) AND SCANNER_ID = ? AND PD_START_TIME = ? AND STOP_NUMBER = ?]]></value>
 </property> 
 </bean>
```

Here are the getter and setter methods in my DaoImpl:

```
private static String gpsDataSql = null;

private static String gpsDataAllStopsSql = null;

public static String getGpsDataSql() {
    return gpsDataSql;
}

public static void setGpsDataSql(String gpsDataSql) {
    DataDaoImpl.gpsDataSql = gpsDataSql;
}

public static String getGpsDataAllStopsSql() {
    return gpsDataAllStopsSql;
}

public static void setGpsDataAllStopsSql(String gpsDataAllStopsSql) {
    DataDaoImpl.gpsDataAllStopsSql = gpsDataAllStopsSql;
}
```

Is there something my eyes are gliding over or could it be another issue with my environment?

Thanks!

Comment: May be  that static keyword in setter method signature.

Comment: Excatly: Why you are having static fields and methods for getters and setters. Better option is to have spring bean with singleton scope - if rest of the dao code is stateless.

Comment: Wow did gloss over that one.  Thanks.  I'm sure that's it as Eclipse by default is set to static on my machine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bean you are declaring in the XML tries to set properties that exists on the `DataDaoImpl` class. For this to work properly, remove the static members and try the following for your class:

```
package com.text.service.dao;

public class DataDaoImpl extends SomeOtherDaoWhereDataSourceIsDefined {
    private String gpsDataAllStopsSql;
    private String gpsDataSql;

    public String getGpsDataAllStopsSql() {
        return gpsDataAllStopsSql;
    }

    public void setGpsDataAllStopsSql(String gpsDataAllStopsSql) {
        this.gpsDataAllStopsSql = gpsDataAllStopsSql;
    }

    public String getGpsDataSql() {
        return gpsDataSql;
    }

    public void setGpsDataSql(String gpsDataSql) {
        this.gpsDataSql = gpsDataSql;
    }
}
```

[This article](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html) explains the usage of static vs non static members.